# Cannot update usages on node.js stripe subscription

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

When trying to upgrade a subscription usage I am getting this error:

Error: No such subscription item: sub_00000000000 (livemode=false)

The code I am doing it through is this:

```
    const res = await client.usageRecords.create('sub_00000000000', {
        quantity: count,
        action: "set"
    });
```

I checked the stripe panel, and the subscription id exists. Also, note that the subscription is a trialing one.

Comment: Are you sure about the number of 0 ?

Comment: `I checked the stripe panel, and the subscription id exists` : yes, but does it exist in test mode or live mode, and which mode is your API call being executed in? :)

Comment: @karllekko I assume OP is in test mode, as the error reports

Comment: I changed the subscription id to something private and also checked same key is being used in both subscription creation and usage creation.

Comment: @Seblor, yes, it does exist in test mode.

Comment: The error you are having can be caused by the subscription beeing canceled. Check the end date.

Comment: @Seblor, logging it gives this: ended_at: null

Comment: @TheodorB is it canceled on the dashboard ?

Comment: No, it says: Trialing until 2018/06/23

Comment: Just as an FYI Stripe object IDs are safe to share publicly, you don't need to redact them.

Comment: Also, I think maybe you should pass a _subscription item_ ID(looks like si_xxx) to that endpoint in the current version of the API, not the subscription ID

Comment: I see, how can I retrieve that one ?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#subscription_object-items-data-id

Comment: Worked alright, I added an answer for people who have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alrght, so it seems like, as the comments suggested, the usageRecords is expecting a token that looks like si_00000000000 instead of sub_00000000000.

Answer (score 2):

Please instead of using the subscription id, use the subscription item id :

$subscription_item_id = Subscription::retrieve($subscription_id)->items->data[0]->id;

I had the same problem and this worked for me. I hope this helps.